# Marko JS on-submit

Tags: javascript, node.js, marko

I can't get this to work, it will not `console.log(this.stat.first_name)` , I need to know how to access the input form values that are entered so I can change state and then make an `axios` post request in the `postSubmit` function. I am doing the `console.log` first to test it and get data movement correct.

Anything will help.

First question was deleted, this is a repost as I did not figure the problem out.

```
class {
  onCreate() {
    this.state = {
      first_name: null,
      last_name: null,
      email: null,
      address: null,
      phone_number: null,
      email_promotion_optin: false
    };
  }
  postSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.state.first_name = event.target.name.first_name;
    console.log(this.state.first_name);
  }
}

<form on-click('postSubmit')>
  <fieldset>
    <legend> Create Customer</legend>
      <div>
        <label>
          First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>
          Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>
          Email: <input type="text" name="email">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>
          Address: <input type="text" name="address">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>
          Phone Number: <input type="text" name="phone_number">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>
          Submit <input type="submit">
        </label>
      </div>
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

UPDATE!!!!!!:

I have come up with this from MarkoJS documentation, but still no luck. I may be on the right route or I may be polluting my code with a lot of unnecessary crap.

```
$ const axios = require('axios');

class {
  onCreate() {
    this.state = {
        first_name: '',
        last_name: '',
        email: '',
        address: '',
        phone_number: '',
        email_promotion_optin: false
    };
  }

  onFirstNameInput () {
    this.state.first_name = this.getEl('firstName').value;
  }

  onLastNameInput () {
    this.state.last_name = this.getEl('lastName').value;
  }

  onEmailInput () {
    this.state.email = this.getEl('email').value;
  }

  onAddressInput () {
    this.state.address = this.getEl('address').value;
  }

  onPhoneNumberInput () {
    this.state.phone_number = this.getEl('phoneNumber').value;
  }

  postSubmit() {
    axios.post('/api/v1/customers', this.state)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }

}



<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend> Create Customer</legend>
    <div>
      <label>
        First Name: <input type="text" key="firstName" on-input('onFirstNameInput')>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>
        Last Name: <input type="text" key="last_name" on-input('oneLastNameInput')>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>
        Email: <input type="text" key="email" on-input('onEmailInput')>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>
        Address: <input type="text" key="address" on-input('onAddressInput')>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>
        Phone Number: <input type="text" key="phone_number" on-input('onPhoneNumberInput')>
      </label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <div>
    <button on-click('postSubmit')>Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You could try using a button as the `Submit` and calling your `postSubmit` function there.

Comment: Would you like to help me by giving an example of rigging it up to console.log the data?

Comment: Not sure if it works, but using something like `<button on-click('postSubmit')>Submit</submit>`

Comment: I am still coming up with blanks, this has been frustrating. I do believe the problem lies in the definition of the `postSubmit()` function itself. I am unsure if the way I am trying to grab the data from the `event` object is correct. It may not even be `event` I need to use, but I cannot find any real life examples of it anywhere with marko (that is marko and forms and text input fields). We will wait and see what the community comes up with while I screw around with it for a few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into the issue. The reason that the code is not working as expected is that the properties on the `this.state` object are not defined as `enumerable`. MarkoJS uses `Object.defineProperty` to create getters and setters for the state properties, but it is not explicitly setting the `enumerable` property to `true` so it is defaulting to `false`. I think we should fix this and opened up a GitHub issue to discuss: https://github.com/marko-js/marko/issues/964

In the meantime, I recommend the following workaround to explicitly copy over the properties that should be submitted with the HTTP post:

```
postSubmit() {
  var request = {
    first_name: this.state.first_name,
    last_name: this.state.last_name,
    email: this.state.email,
    address: this.state.address,
    phone_number: this.state.phone_number,
    email_promotion_optin: this.state.email_promotion_optin
  }

  axios.post('/api/v1/customers', request)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

Comment: This is so incredibly brittle, I can't believe it's an accepted answer.